# Lookup table or similar within the Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp32

Good day,

I am receiving userIds as integer on an ESP32, I would like to convert them to the corresponding name. Currently I solve this with the switch statement as shown below. Is there a more elegant solution?

```
   String ReturnName(int userId) {
      Switch(userId) {
      case 20:
        {
          return "John";
        }
        break;
      case 44:
        {
          return "Maria";
        }
        break;
      case 4:
        {
          return "Herrensen";
        }
        break;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all having a break after a return doesn't make sense. Remove them.

```
  Switch(userId) {
  case 4:  return "Herrensen";
  case 20: return "John";
  case 44: return "Maria";
  }
```

Isn't to bad imho.

Alternatively you could use an array.

```
const char* lut[45];
lut[20] = "John";
lut[44] = "Maria";
lut[4] = "Herrensen";
```

But this is not very memory efficient if you don't have consecutive user ids. At the moment you have reserved memory for 45 pointers but only used 3 so most of the memory is wasted. and you have to make sure that you only index valid elements within the array.

You could use a hash table but that is usually not a good idea on Arduino due to limited memory.

Answer (score 1):

For an ESP32 target, you might consider a std::map

```
#include <map>
std::map<byte, const char*> list;

void setup() {
  list[4] = "Anna";
  list[20]= "John"; 
  Serial.begin(115200);

  for (auto const & n : list) {
    Serial.print(n.first); Serial.print(":"); Serial.println(n.second);
  }
}
```

An ESP is not as restricted in RAM and c++ stdlib as a real Arduino